# Get position of @keyframe animated element

Tags: css, css-animations

```
@keyframes myAnim {
    0% {
        bottom: 47.5%;
        left: 29%;
    }
    70% {
        bottom: 70%;
        left: 64%;
    }
    100% {
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 64%;
    }
}
```

The animation with the values bottom and left in percentage may not be the same exact location as we want. So using firebug, it's not possible to inspect while running the animation. So, I tried to inspect by using paused method but seems wrong:

```
@keyframes myAnim {
    0% {
        bottom: 47.5%;
        left: 29%;
    }
    70% {
        bottom: 70%;
        left: 64%;
        animation-play-state: paused;
    }
    /* so that I can inspect and set the percentage*/
    100% {
        bottom: 0%;
        left: 64%;
    }
}
```

Is there any technique that we can inspect the values of running animation?

Answer (score 0):

Set the animation to that

```
@keyframes myAnim{
    0%{bottom: 47.5%; left: 29%;}
    100%{bottom: 70%; left: 64%;}
  /*
    100%{bottom: 0%; left: 64%;}
  */
}
```

and in the element set *forwards* for the animation-fill-mode property.

This way the animation will end at the state that had in the 70% keyframe

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Looks like you need to set the last keyframe to 100%. I thought that the last keyframe value would extend up to the animation end.